# How can I 'manually' create a Session object in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, session

CodeIgniter creates a session object when a page is loaded. It looks for a specific cookie. (Set somewhere in config). It gets the session id and based on that creates a session object - which you can then manipulate.

I have a need to do this 'manually'. I have a session id. I want to create a session object based on that session id and add data to it. This is different from the 'default' session I have  - which CI  has automatically created.

The reason for doing this is there is a re-direct from one site to another (though both use the same back-end and session storage). On site A I want to set something into the session which is then opened on Site B. At the moment the session id is created on Site A. Site B picks this up and creates a session based on it. Now I want to pre-populate the session object on Site A.

Is this possible and how would I go about it?

Thanks

--JustinWyllie

Answer (score 1):

You can share the session by saving into the database on Site A and retrieve it on Site B, you can have a look here: 
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html.